# Getting ClassNotFoundException by using new Kafka Version 2.1.0 with Apache Storm 1.2.2 in Kafka Spout

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

While starting a topology with Kafka Spout with new Kafka version 2.1.0 and Storm version 1.2.2 getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.api.OffsetRequest. I don't get this when I use Kafka version 0.10.0.1. Can you guys please help as I want to be on latest Kafka version?

I have tried all the latest kafka version starting with 2.*. But not of it works.Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.api.OffsetRequest

Comment: Post your pom.xml (the dependency section), and we'll have an easier time helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kafka.api` is the old Scala classes. [Many of these were removed in Kafka `2.x`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/2.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/api)

The majority of those classes were moved to [`org.apache.kafka.common.requests`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/requests/), and there is `ListOffsetRequest` and `OffsetFetchRequest`, so not sure which you're trying to use.

If Storm itself is depending on these old APIs, then you are bound to those, your own processor cannot use the new APIs.

Plus, the Kafka server version itself only supports certain API calls of these new request classes.

Comment: These are the classes in the topology config I am using
className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.StringScheme"
className: "org.apache.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme"
className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkHosts"
className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.SpoutConfig"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583718/8845188), I suspect you're using the `storm-kafka` library for Kafka integration. You need to migrate to `storm-kafka-client`, which is based on the new Kafka APIs. The documentation for the new module can be found [here](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.2/storm-kafka-client.html).

If you need to migrate committed offsets from `storm-kafka`, you can use the utility at https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka-migration. It will let you migrate without having to start over on your Kafka partitions.

Comment: After changing to Storm Kafka Client I am now getting this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.kafka.StringScheme while started the topology using the flux yml file

Comment: Did you update your topology code to use the new KafkaSpout? `storm-kafka-client` is a new library, you will need to rewrite your configuration to use the new APIs. StringScheme only exists in `storm-kafka`. The table for mapping to new config at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/docs/storm-kafka-client.md#mapping-from-storm-kafka-to-storm-kafka-client-spout-properties may be helpful.